# How to map json data using codable and populate to table view?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a network request using urlsession and got json data , but don't know how to map the data and populate into table view . I am a beginner please help me out.

Here is the json data :

```
{
page = 1;
results =     (
            {
        adult = 0;
        "backdrop_path" = "/w2PMyoyLU22YvrGK3smVM9fW1jj.jpg";
        "genre_ids" =             (
            28,
            12,
            878
        );
        id = 299537;
        "original_language" = en;
        "original_title" = "Captain Marvel";
    }) }
```

Here is my code so far:

```
var movies = [Movies]()

do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            print(json)
            self.parse(json: json as! Data)
            
        } catch {
            print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

func parse(json: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let jsonUsers = try? decoder.decode([Movies].self, from: json) {
        self.movies = jsonUsers
        print(movies[0].request)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not JSON and your code crashes because `json` is a dictionary and cannot be cast to `Data`. And either use `JSONSerializaton` **or** `JSONDecoder` but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Swift.  If you search here on Stack Overflow (and elsewhere around the web) you will find a great many examples on how to decode JSON Swift.

Apple's documentation on the subject can be found here:

[Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

With a code sample here:

[Using JSON with Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types/)

Generally speaking, you will need to create a struct to represent the decoded data.  That struct will derive from decodable.  You should give it a "CodingKeys" value that will define how the fields in your struct map to the keys in the JSON.  You then use the decoder to create and fill out that struct.

`JSONDecoder` is the more recent and type-safe mechanism for decoding JSON.  `JSONSerialization` will be more challenging for a beginner because of typecasting so I recommend you stick with `JSONDecoder`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the json data I assume that you're using TMDB's API.

Firstly, you should create a decodable struct for the results:

```
struct SearchResult: Decodable {
    let page: Int
    let results: [Movie]
    let totalPages: Int
    let totalResults: Int
}
```

Secondly, you should fetch the results from the API. I suggest that you do it with the following code:

```
func searchURL(withQuery query: String) -> URL? {
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = "api.themoviedb.org"
    components.path = "/3/search/movie"
    components.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "query", value: query),
        URLQueryItem(name: "api_key", value: "YOUR-API-KEY")
    ]
    return components.url
}
```

This function will return an optional URL to the search results, if you'll call it with "Pulp Fiction" as a query, it'll return:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=Pulp%20Fiction&api_key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

You can use it to actually fetch the searched phrase from the API:

```
func search(_ text: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Movie], Error>) -> Void) {
    if let url = getSearchURL(withQuery: text) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, _ in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

                    let decodedSearchResult = try decoder.decode(SearchResult.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(decodedSearchResult.results))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The following code:

```
search("Pulp Fiction") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let items):
        for item in items {
            print(item.title)
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

will print:

```
Pulp Fiction
Pulp Fiction: The Facts
Pulp Fiction Art
Stealing Pulp Fiction
Pulp Fiction: the Golden Age of Storytelling
UFOTV Presents: Pulp Fiction: The Golden Age of Storytelling
Pulpe Fiction
```

If you want to populate a tableView with the search results, you should replace the .success case with:

```
search("Pulp Fiction") { [weak self] result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let items):
        self?.searchResults = items
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```